# Laravel middleware error when i implode the excepted pages

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Hello there im getting 403 when i pass an variable to the middleware this is my constructer function:**

```
    public function __construct(XristesRepository $xristesRepo)
{
    $table = Table::where('model_name', 'Xristes')->first();

    $this->xristesRepository = $xristesRepo;

    $this->permissions = Auth::user()->getPermissions(Auth::user()->id, $table->id);

    $perms = [];

    if (in_array('create', $this->permissions)) {
        $perms[] = '\'create\', \'store\' ';
    };

    if (in_array('edit', $this->permissions)) {
        $perms[] = '\'edit\', \'update\' ';
    };

    if (in_array('delete', $this->permissions)) {
        $perms[] = '\'destroy\'';
    };

    $perms = '\'index\', ' .implode(',', $perms);

    $this->middleware('userPermissions', ['except' => [$perms]]);
}
```

**The output of the perms variable is:**

> 'index', 'create', 'store', 'edit', 'update','destroy'

**When i paste the above output in the middleware like:**

```
$this->middleware('userPermissions', ['except' => ['index', 'create', 'store', 'edit', 'update','destroy']]);
```

**Everything works fine can anyone help me please where is the problem becaue im getting the same result but when i use the variable doesnt work when i paste the output it works fine**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$perms` array is wrong.

Here you are adding create and store as a string :

```
if (in_array('create', $this->permissions)) {
    $perms[] = '\'create\', \'store\' ';
};
```

Then you are addding `edit` and `update` as second element to array.

Better option would be :

```
$perms = ['index'];

if (in_array('create', $this->permissions)) {
    array_push($perms, 'create', 'store');
};

if (in_array('edit', $this->permissions)) {
    array_push($perms, 'edit', 'update');
};

if (in_array('delete', $this->permissions)) {
    array_push($perms, 'destroy');
};
```

Comment: Beside the answer. You will see the right tick mark. Click on it.